# .htaccess RewriteRule being ignored and could use a second set of eyes on it

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm missing something in my htaccess file and i need a second set of eyes on it.

Here is what i want to have happen:

```
blog.mysite.com -> www.mysite/about/blog
blog.mysite.com/post/1231231/article-title -> www.mysite.com/article-title
```

Here's what I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.mysite\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/about/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^post/1231231/article-title http://www.mysite.com/article-title  [R=301,L]
```

Here's what i'm getting:

```
blog.mysite.com/post/1231231/article-title -> www.mysite.com/about/blog/post/1231231/article-title
```

My thought is that the first rewrite rule is executing and the ones following it are not being looked at. Not sure what i'm overlooking... :)

EDIT:: FIle now looks like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^post/1231231/article-title1 http://www.mysite.com/article-title1  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^post/1231232/article-title2 http://www.mysite.com/article-title2  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^post/1231233/article-title3 http://www.mysite.com/article-title3  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/about/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Only article-title1 is redirecting properly.

Comment: Is this a cms of some kind like wordpress?

Comment: I LIE!!! The destination site is in wordpress, the origin site is not. The origin site was a home grown cms and there's a handful of articles (thus RewriteRules) that are being redirected to preserve SEO for those articles.

Answer (score 0):

Your second redirect is getting gobbled up by the first rule, because `(.*)` will match **everything**, including `post/1231231/article-title`. So you need to rearrange the order as well as duplicating the rewrite condition. The `RewriteCond` directive only applied to the immediate following `RewriteRule`, so any rules following that rule will not have any conditions applied.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^post/1231231/article-title http://www.mysite.com/article-title  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/about/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can make the `/post/123/title` more generalized if you change the `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteRule ^post/[0-9]+/(.+)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Jon, I have several of these rules:
`RewriteRule ^post/1231231/article-title http://www.mysite.com/article-title  [R=301,L]`
that pertain to several differnt pages, only the first one is working...